# How to use an increment an average formula by more than one row and show the result i n columns in excel?

Tags: excel

This formula

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(B$2:B$31,30*(ROWS(D$2:D2)-1),0))
```

calculates the average of 30 values and shows the results in rows.
B$2:B$31 represents the first range I want to average, 30 is the number of rows to increment each time. The first average will be showed in rows. D2 is the start cell.

**How can I increment 30 rows at a time and show the average in columns starting from column I2**

How can I achieve this without having to manually type in the cell reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to this formula in `I2`

`=AVERAGE(OFFSET($B2:$B31,30*(COLUMNS($I2:I2)-1),0))`

copy formula across